# Swift 2: cannot cast value of type NSArray toNSString Dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am making a simple app to support parents of kids with autism to promote communication. It should be easy since I have a set of code for previous project, but what I stuck was a array of image files in the dictionary. I'm still new and after searching, but none of what I thought would work doesn't work. Why? What should I need to do? (I even gave up array and changed to dictionary, but still problem!)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct WordList {

var placeCue: String?
var choiceImage: [UIImage] = []
var audio: [String] = []

init(index: Int){
let wordlistLibrary = WordlistLibrary().wordlists
let wordlistEntry = wordlistLibrary[index]

let iconName = wordlistEntry["choiceImage"]! as! String // When I run, this is the place to stuck. :(
choiceImage += [UIImage(named: iconName)!]

//choiceImage += wordlistEntry["choiceImage"] as! [UIImage]
placeCue = wordlistEntry["placeCue"] as! String!
audio += wordlistEntry["audio"] as! [String]
}
}
```

---

Below is a part of my dictionary.

```
struct WordlistLibrary {

var  wordlists: [[String: AnyObject]] = [

[
"placeCue": "Audio0",   // toothache
"choiceImage": ["WaterBottle.pdf", "Medicine.pdf", "Dentist.pdf", "SomethingElse.pdf"],
"audio": ["Audio16", "Audio17", "Audio14", "Audio21"]
],

[
"placeCue": "Audio1",   // ear
"choiceImage": ["WaterBottle.pdf", "Medicine.pdf", "Nap.pdf", "SomethingElse.pdf"],
"audio": ["Audio16", "Audio17", "Audio18", "Audio21"]
]
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `choiceImage` is `[String]`. It's not `String`

So change it to

```
let iconName = wordlistEntry["choiceImage"]! as! [String]
choiceImage = iconName.map{ UIImage(named: $0)! }
```